# Enterprise Library 5.0 Logging exception on startup

Tags: c#, .net, logging, .net-4.5, enterprise-library

The application is running on multiple clients. Today I had an incident, where after a power failure, the application was not starting again.

Following are the exceptions from the event log

```
Faulting application name: MyApplication.exe, version: 7.3.0.14, time stamp: 0x626786ff
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.24561, time stamp: 0x5f76968d
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x0000c5af
Faulting process id: 0xeb4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8d17277e726c1
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\Visu\MyApplication.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: b5b2baf1-3d65-11ed-b8b3-00139548ead0
```

Detailed exception

```
Application: MyApplication.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Xml.XmlException
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(System.Exception)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
   at System.Configuration.XmlUtil..ctor(System.IO.Stream, System.String, Boolean, System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.InitConfigFromFile()

Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(System.Object, System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs)

Exception Info: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.OnConfigRemoved(System.Object, System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.OnConfigRemoved(System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigEventArgs)
   at System.Configuration.Internal.InternalConfigRoot.RemoveConfigImpl(System.String, System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(System.String)
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(System.String)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceSection.GetConfigurationSourceSection()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.SetCurrentContainerIfNotSet()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.EnterpriseLibraryContainer.get_Current()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.get_Writer()
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Logger.Write(System.Object, System.String, Int32, Int32)
   at MyApplication.App.Main(System.String[])
```

Code:

```
[System.STAThreadAttribute()]
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Logger.Write("Application was started on:" + DateTime.Now, "Core", 100, 100);
  ...
}
```

As I had no possiblity for remote debugger, I copied the complete application folder from the client to my dev machine. Everything was working properly. The application started and the UI was displayed.

On the client machine I tried the following

- checked the application.config file - everything OK
- starting the application with administrative rights - same exception
- moving the folder from the "program files" directory to somewhere different, including all configuration files - same exception
- comparing the current application folder with initial folder after the setup, all files are equal - same exception

As a last point, i updated the code of the main method with a try catch block around the call to the Enterprise Logger. I compiled the exe and started the updated version on the client computer. Only the exe and manifest file have been updated!
The application started and the catch block was never triggered.

I switched back to the "previously corrupted?" version and now it was successfully running.

From the text i assume that something must be wrong the the app.config file. But then it would also throw the exception on my dev machine and would still throw the exception after the update of the app.exe.

What could be the reason of the above exception?

Comment: The exception complains that the XML configuration for Entlib is invalid. We can't guess what how it was configured, whether it reads settings from another file or what `app.config` or that file look like. Entlib is obsolete for **over 10 years** now and even the people that used it would have trouble remembering how it worked.

Comment: If a config file is bad you can't fix it by changing permissions or moving files around. Entlib reads configuration from app.config and/or additional files. The full application configuration isn't just app.config or web.config though. These settings are combined with `machine.config`. If you're sure you replaced all application files, perhaps `machine.config` is corrupt. You can use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see what files are opened by the application before the crash

Comment: What operating system are you using.  Looks like code target is Net 4.0 and the operating system is at least Win 7 or new because it is 64 bit using syswow64.  Net 4.0 was released when WinXP was latest OS around 2008.  Win7 was released in 2009 and initial version has option for either 32 bit or 64 bit.  After black out, was machine rebuilt?  Did they install Win7 32 or 64 bit version?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos
The application was programmed 8 years ago and during development other libraries were dependent on Enterprise Library 5.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Only the app.config is used. It was my first thought that something in there was currupt. I compared the config file and checked it but i have not found any sign of corruption. I copied the faulty version from the customer to my development machine and there it starts successfully. No other *.configs are used.
As the solution to solve the problem was to recompile the app.exe file and and exchanged only this file, I am wondering where the problem could arise.

Comment: And yet the program doesn't work. The error says the file on the customer machine is corrupt. You'll have to check what file that is. Use procmon to find what file is accessed when the error occurs. It may *not* be the app.config file. We don't know what the application does or where it loads its settings from. You *can* configure a section of app.config to load settings from another XML file. You *can* configure Entlib to load settings outside app.config, although that doesn't seem to be the case here

Comment: Only the app.config is used for the configuration of the Enterprise Library

Comment: @jdweng .Net 4.6.1, Windows 10 Embedded, 64bit

Comment: So use procmon. We can't guess what's going on on that machine. There's no code, no configuration file, we have no idea what's installed or not.

Comment: Exception says :"Framework Version: v4.0.30319" which is Net 4.0.  The exception doesn't say what version of windows.  SysWow64 only exists on Win7 64 bit version of later.  When Net 4.0 was release it was before Win7 was released.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos you have been right, problem was a *.config. In this case the AppData\Local\.....\user.config. The file was filled with '\0'. So I will have to find a way to check it.

Comment: I've forgotten about `user.config`. Configuration in .NET Framework is hierarchical. The app.config contents are merged with machine.config, user.config and if the machine is joined to a domain, the domain's config. Typically those files contain some default settings and don't affect applications. Unless they're broken.

Answer (score 0):

With the tips from @PanagiotisKanavos the solution of the problem was possible.

Checking the file access with procmon, i realised that there was a user.config file stored at C:<Users><Username>\AppData\Local<MyCompany><MyApp><AppVersion>.
This file was corrupt - filled with '\0' - due to the power failure.
At startup the user.config file was merged with the app.config file and this crashed the application.